# Changing Gutenberg / WP block editor width only on pages, not posts or other taxonomies

Tags: filters, css, wp-admin, block-editor, admin-css

I have managed to change the width of the **WordPress block editor** so it uses my max width of my actual theme, making it easier to do layouts during the writing process. Now I wanted to change that to **only** happen when I edit **pages**, *not posts* or other taxonomies.

How do I do that?

**My current procedure is:**

Add these lines to my theme´s **functions.php** file:

```
add_theme_support( 'editor-styles' ); 
add_editor_style( 'style-editor.css' );
```

Then add this css to my **style-editor.css** file:

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {

  /* Main column width */
  .wp-block { width: 90%; max-width: 1170px; }

  /* Width of "wide" blocks */
  .wp-block[data-align="wide"] { max-width: 1170px; }

  /* Width of "full-wide" blocks */
  .wp-block[data-align="full"] { max-width: none; }

}
```

So far so good, the block editor displays the new width, but when I add the filter for making this only on pages, with what I assume is `is_page`, it does not work and I end up getting the normal wp editor width. Here is the code in **functions.php**:

```
if ( is_page() ) {

    add_theme_support( 'editor-styles' );
    add_editor_style( 'style-editor.css' );

}
```

I guess my problem is that I am using the front-end is_page hook, but I cannot find the wp editor equivalent of that. What is the proper code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the WordPress hook `add_theme_support( 'editor-styles' );` adds the css in the style-editor.css and appends the class `.editor-styles-wrapper` before my `.wp-block`, the usage of the body classes for page vs. post styles fails. Instead I use the answer from [here, from David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/add-custom-css-wordpress-admin), to add the styles independently to the wp admin area:

```
// Update CSS within in Admin
function admin_style() {
  wp_enqueue_style('admin-styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/style-editor.css');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_style');
```

Css code, as answered by @RiddleMeThis, works well now and I can differentiate between the post/page types:

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {

  /* Main column width - pages */
  .post-type-page .wp-block { width: 90%; max-width: 1170px; }

  /* Main column width - posts */
  .post-type-post .wp-block { width: 60%; max-width: 800px; }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this ! Saved me a lot of time trying to understand why my CSS was changed when imported, and why my `.post-type-post .editor-styles-wrapper .wp-block` was not working...

Answer (score 0):

In the admin, if you inspect the body tag you will see WP is adding specific classess, similar to on the frontend.  With that said you can use this class to be more specific in your CSS rules.

For example, your code could do this to target when editing pages only ...

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {

    /* Main column width */
    .post-type-page .wp-block { width: 90%; max-width: 1170px; }

    /* Width of "wide" blocks */
    .post-type-page .wp-block[data-align="wide"] { max-width: 1170px; }

    /* Width of "full-wide" blocks */
    .post-type-page .wp-block[data-align="full"] { max-width: none; }

}
```

Comment: This solution is good but for the fact that my choice of `add_theme_support( 'editor-styles' );`line is inserting the styles from style-editor.css appending the `.editor-styles-wrapper` in front of the style I added, the `.wp-block` style. Thus it cannot be used with the body class that you suggested above, not directly anyway. They do not show up at all. *Not* with my *functions.php solution*. But I added a solution based on this, your css selector solution, with a more general admin-code append. Thanks.